# Django: use POST or links, which is better practice?

Tags: django

A noobish question to be sure.

```
<a href="{% url 'stuff.views.SomeView' %}/somethingnew">
    <button>See something new on this page</button>
</a>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <button name="somethingnew" type="submit" value=True>See something new on this page</button>
</form>
```

With either choice, I update some boolean variable, perform the appropriate calculations, call the page view and render a page with `something new on this page`. Part of the reason I use either method is to save the state of a collection of boolean variables. What is the best way 1) change a boolean variable 2) save its state 3) perform the necessary updates when the button is clicked and finally 4) render page after the underlying data has been updated?

Right now, I am using forms rather than links so that I don't need to code a url for each boolean variable. Which method is better? Will one method improve the time it takes to reload the page (assuming many boolean variables)?

Comment: "Update a boolean variable/save its state": where is it saved? In the session object?

Comment: It's saved to a Model currently, but I am thinking of moving the variables into an Object which I pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Following the REST mindset, a POST request is in order to transmit the user input, since you are altering database objects.

2) I'd save it in the Session object if the input is not needed forever (session duration). Otherwise in the database as you are doing now.

3/4) I'd gather all the necessary info in a form. When the user commits the form in a POST request, I'd compute the data and respond with the rendered page containing the computed result. If the input variables are gathered step by step with intermittent computation, I'd just update the input form accordingly (display different choices in a combo box or something like that). Of course the transmitting could be done in an AJAXy way, too.